# Webview: Differentiate "Open in Popup" and "Open in New tab"

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, popup

I have a WebView in my window which loads some HTML, and I wish to know, whenever I click on a link which creates a window, whether it's a popup or a "new tab" link (i.e. with the `target="_blank"` attribute in the `a` tag).

So here are some parts of my code

When the class initializes:

```
[mainWebView setUIDelegate:self];
[mainWebView setPolicyDelegate:self];
```

Further down in the same class, the implementation of the delegates:

```
- (WebView*)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"The request is %@", request);
    return sender;
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(NSString *)frame decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
{
    NSLog(@"New window!");

}
```

So the `createWebViewWithRequest` callback is called whenever a new window is to be created (popup or newtab link), which is normal. But the `decidePolicyForNewWindowAction` is never called, no matter what sort of link it is.

There seems to be a guy [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/webkitsdk-dev/2005/Nov/msg00121.html) who has the same problem as me, but I still can't find any solution to this.

Comment: This delegate helped me `createWebViewWithRequest `, thanks. And I also have the `decidePolicyForNewWindowAction` not firing issue, but I have `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` fired instead. The reason is that my `<a>` tag is not actually doing the job, it triggers some JS codes and it did something like `window.location = xxx`, so it ultimately leads to `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` instead of `decidePolicyForNewWindowAction`. Not sure if you have the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:` works OK for `target="_blank"` links. If you show more code (best of all - a sample project), I'll try to compare it to my version (if you still need this, of course). :)